# RESTHeart database create

Tags: mongodb, curl, restheart

I am using [RESTHeart](http://restheart.org/) to access a Mongo database. RESTHeart has a an API that is supposed to create a database, e.g.:

```
curl -X put http://localhost:8080/db1
```

Well, I was using a chrome browser-based REST client that happened to do the equivalent of the follow curl call, but I accidentally forgot to nuke the data portion. It contained the JSON `{"e":"f"}` for data.

```
curl -X put -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"e":"f"}' http://localhost:8080/db2`
```

When I then tried to do a curl get, it returns a value with the key/value pair `"e":"f"` stuffed in there - which is not what I want.

```
$ curl  http://localhost:8080/db2
```

> ... { "_id" : "db2" , "e" : "f" , "_etag" : { "$oid" : "570f90601d956327e8df28c4"} , "_size" : 0 , "_total_pages" : 0 , "_returned" : 0}

Now, using the Mongo shell, I try to find this key/value pair using just about every [Mongo shell command](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/). But, I can't find it, nor can I remove it either. In fact, I can create a rather large Mongo database, then do that curl put, and I'm screwed, but it then adds the pair to my nice clean database.

Does anyone know how I can remove that strange key/value pair, either using Mongo shell, or the RESTHeart API - short of nuking the database and recreating it from scratch?! Thanks.

Comment: Restheart allows to define properties for dbs and collections resources as well

Answer (score 0):

To remove the db property just update the db:

With PATCH:

`PATCH /db {"$unset": {"e": null}}`

Or with PUT

```
PUT /db {}
```

For more info look at the documentation [reference sheet](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/SoCM) and [representation format](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/UICM)

Comment: I see you're referring to the SoftInstigate Wiki quite a lot. However, it seems to be a closed environment. Is it possible to get access?

Comment: @Ralph this is an old answer. The documentation of RESTHeart has been moved to https://restheart.org/docs